# How to query for TFS work items with or without tags

Tags: tfs, tags, tfs-workitem

TFS supports querying on tags, but I can't find a way to create a TFS work item query to return results that have no tags or any tag.

It is not possible to sort the Tag column in the TFS web access, so I can't even return all work items and then sort on the column to focus on those with tags and those without tags.

For example, I was hoping to see a wild card or any for the Tags value below:

[image]

Comment: Like Martin suggests use Tags / Does not contain / blank.  But you can sort on the backlog, it's priority locked.  You can sort a query in the query editor.  Click on the column options

Comment: Tags Does Not Contain blank does is invalid - error "cannot be used in conjunction with an empty string". Putting Tags Does Not Contain "" returns all work items with and without tags.  As indicated in my OP, you cannot sort on Tags column.

Answer (score 3):

I'm about a year too late, but I just accomplished this by doing Tags, Does Not Contain, "". I know that makes no sense, but it worked. I was able to pull in a task that had no tag.

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't work for me. In my example above, if I do Tags, Does Not Contain, "" it has no effect on the query. I get results with and without tags. In fact if I do Tags, Contains, "" then I get zero results, presumably because "" is not a tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly helpful in the tool, but works to get the information. I select all, copy, paste into a worksheet. I can format as table and sort the results to get what I need. It is not very helpful for in tool info, but it works. Another option is to install the TFS Plugin with Excel, you can create and modify items using an existing query, sort items, add items, filter to show only items that do not have a tag, etc.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score -2):

Can you do Tags=""?

I am not sure I understand the use case, but you can sugest new features on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks but empty quotes does not seem to mean anything to TFS in this context.  See reply to Etienne above.