# Is there a way to find all item (Product Backlog Item, Bugs, Task) without any Tags included? (With Query)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm am querying across my project and want to find all item that don't have any Tags. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query for TFS work items with or without tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882121/how-to-query-for-tfs-work-items-with-or-without-tags)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk the answer on that question is not correct! the presented solution not work in online AzureDevops!

Comment: I meant to say that is not possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is **not** possible to query all the work items without tags.

There is a  feature request about it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366546/i-would-like-to-have-possibility-to-query-for-work.html).

As workaround, you can add to all non-tagged work items a specific tag to mark them and then query this tag.

You can use Rest API to get the work items, then filter the results to get the non-tagged work items.

Small script in PowerShell:

```
$user = ""
$token = "YOUR-PAT-HERE"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $token)))
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{queryGuid}?api-version=5.0"
$workItems = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-Host "Work Items without Tags:"
$workItems.workItems.ForEach({
  $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$($_.id)?api-version=5.0"
  $workItemDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
  if($workItemDetails.fields.'System.Tags' -eq $null
  { Write-Host $_.id }
})
```